# Open Xava: How to set the current_timestamp while insert in Open Xava?

Tags: java, jpa, openxava

I'm trying insert current_timestamp to a database column "CREATION_DATE" when user is doing a create and set the current_timestamp to a database column "MODIFY_DATE" when user is doing an edit, but i failed. Code:

```
@Column(name = "CREATEDATE", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON INSERT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createDate;

@Column(name = "MODIFYDATE", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date modifyDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two callback methods to your entity:

```
@PrePersist
private void setCreateDate() {
    createDate = new Date();
}

@PreUpdate
private void updateModifyDate() {
    modifyDate = new Date();
}
```